# ionic 1, the element with hide-on-keyboard-open class is still hidden eve after the page is reloaded

Tags: ionic-framework

I use hide-on-keyboard-open class to hide a certain part of the page, but after I complete input and reload the page, the hidden element is still invisible。

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].